# How can I prevent my USB mouse to interfere with standby, on Linux?

Tags: linux, mouse, redhat-enterprise-linux, standby

I am using RHEL workstation. My USB mouse interferes with standby - if I press the sleep button, the computer tries to standby, but instantly wakes up. If I remove the USB mouse, standby works.

Update: this only happens when the mouse is plugged in *some* of the USB ports.

How can I fix this? Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen with other USB devices that you plugin?

Comment: No, it doesn't. And I just noticed it happens when I plug the mouse in some ports, and not the others.